# How to send byte array using servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a byte array that is a Message digest. And i want send it to another appliction in same server.I don't want to convert it to string and pull back the array on the other end.

How can i do it using servlet?

Comment: A servlet's output method is a plain `OutputStream`, you can output whatever you like... What prevents you from pushing that byte array at all??

Answer (score 1):

As @fge mentioned in comment  *A servlet's output method is a plain OutputStream, you can output whatever you like*

try

```
InputStream inputsttream=request.getInputStream();
OutputStream outputstream=resp.getOutputStream();
byte[] bytebuffer = new byte[size];
for (int bits= inputsttream.read(bytebuffer); bits!=-1; bits= inputsttream.read(bytebuffer))
{
    outputstream.write(bytebuffer , 0, bits);
}
```

Comment: i want to send byte array to another application and i need to read it from that application.can you please explain how to do it?